# Displaying data from xml(fb2) on a website

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc

There are several files with the fb2 extension, the formatting in which may differ from each other, so you need to read the contents of the tags, and depending on their attributes assign them different styles for subsequent transmission to the view

In order to output data from the file to the view, I created a list of strings, to which I added data from the file in html format, then placed this list in the ViewBag, I got the necessary data by iterating through nodes and their child nodes with a foreach loop and a swich-case construction, I repent that this is not the best way, after all, already at this stage I received a hard-to-read code, [An example of how I parsed data from a file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyJc0.png)
, [Example of parsed Xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXL2e.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Refactor it for better readability:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in sections)
{
    foreach (XmlNode childSection in node.ChildNodes)
    {
        switch (childSection.LocalName)
        {
            case "p":
                HandleParagraphNode(childSection);
                break;
            case "emphasis":
                paragraphs.Add($"<p class=\"emphasis\">{childSection.InnerText}</p>");
                break;
            case "image":
                HandleImageNode(childSection);
                break;
        }
    }
}

void HandleParagraphNode(XmlNode paragraphNode)
{
    foreach (XmlNode p in paragraphNode.ChildNodes)
    {
        if (p.LocalName == "strong")
        {
            HandleStrongNode(p);
        }
    }
}

void HandleStrongNode(XmlNode strongNode)
{
    if (strongNode.LastChild.LocalName == "sup")
    {
        paragraphs.Add($"<strong>{strongNode.FirstChild.InnerText}<sup>{strongNode.LastChild.InnerText}</sup></strong>");
    }
    else
    {
        paragraphs.Add($"<h3><strong>{strongNode.InnerText}</strong></h3>");
    }
}

void HandleImageNode(XmlNode imageNode)
{
    var hrefAttribute = imageNode.Attributes["href"]?.Value;
    if (hrefAttribute != null)
    {
        var binaryNode = FindBinaryNodeById(hrefAttribute);
        if (binaryNode != null)
        {
            var imageSrc = $"data:image/jpeg;base64,{binaryNode.InnerText}";
            paragraphs.Add($"<img src=\"{imageSrc}\" />");
        }
    }
}

XmlNode FindBinaryNodeById(string id)
{
    return binaryNodes.FirstOrDefault(node => node.Attributes["id"]?.Value == id);
}
```